# How to read UWSGI parameters in python/flask passed from nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I set up python/flask/uwsgi+nginx web app and it works fine. I want to use geoip, I set it up on nginx side:

```
   location / {
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/qbaka-visit.sock;
            ...
            uwsgi_param     GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
    }
```

But now I don't know how to read this property in python. Prior to uwsgi I used simple flask builtin webserver + nginx proxy_pass, in which case I used `proxy_set_header X-Geo-Country $geoip_country_code;`  and read this argument using `request.headers`, but for UWSGI params I couldn't figure out how to read them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`uwsgi_param` sets a wsgi `environ` key of the given name to the application.  You can use this for headers, which follow the CGI convention of using an `HTTP_` prefix.  the equivalent of your `proxy_set_header` would be:

```
uwsgi_param HTTP_X_GEOIP_COUNTRY $geoip_country_code;
```

note that the header name must be in upper case and with dashes replaced by underscores, to be recognized as a valid header in wsgi.

Alternativly, it looks like the environ is accessible in flask, as `request.environ`, so you could keep your uwsgi_param the same, but read it as `request.environ['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']`.  This is probably preferable, actually, since you can distinguish them from actual request headers that way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't seem to find *official* documentation on setting HTTP headers with `uwsgi_param` anywhere, though. Does anyone happen to have a reference?

Comment: @esmail: the relationship between request headers and the `HTTP_` is not a part of uwsgi, but rather `wsgi`/`pep-333` (see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables).  the `uwsgi_param` sets key-value pairs on the environ dict passed to the application.  In fact, `pep-333` specifically delegates these to the cgi spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.1.18