# How do I configure a Flask-based python app using nginx and uwsgi?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask-based python app that needs a bunch of configuration information (e.g. database connection parameters) on app start.

In my nginx configuration, I can provide parameters using uwsgi_param, as shown in [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133460/how-to-read-uwsgi-parameters-in-python-flask-passed-from-nginx)

However my problem is that the `request.environ` object is not available outside of a request handler, so I can't use it at application start. Furthermore, I'm trying to provide a mostly deployment-agnostic configuration mechanism so that I can test using Flask's embedded server during development and use parameters passed by uWSGI in production.

What's the best way to get configuration into my application so that it's accessible via `os.environ` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#development-production. You always can have development, test and production config, you also can get some settings from OS envarment or specific file.

For example I have config module and import some secret settings (which don't want store with source code) from another module. Then on deploy I just replace file with secret settings. Probably better use for this OS envarement.